# PHP script to copy mysql column to another table

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any easy way to copy one a column in a table to another table without changing the order ?
I am a beginner here. I would be much thankful to you if you could supply in depth answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this query can help you out

```
INSERT INTO second_table SELECT * FROM first_table WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4...n)
```